# Selecting previous hour records in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, date, date-range

I am trying to select post which are added on last hour from current time. I have explored previous questions but they are using fixed date or datetime. To achieve this, I am using following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE post_date >= SUBTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "1:0:0") 
and post_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

This query is not displaying any result. When when I am using it without AND it just working perfect. So, How to select previous hour records using current datimetime as I am using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() for this?

Comment: `WHERE post_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND NOW()`

Comment: Do you really need `<= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`? Can the post date be in the future>?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)?

Comment: this works just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/nGDj02cd

Comment: @Barmar, Yes post can have future dates

Comment: If it works without `AND post_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, all your recent posts must be in the future, you don't have any in the preceding hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, and it works fine for me. If no row is displayed, it means that there is no post_date between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and 1 hour ago.

On the other hand, if we assume that post_date is always going to be less than your CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()( i do not know if it is your case; you didn't specify), as a suggestion, you could improve your code by just simply doing this.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE post_date >= SUBTIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "1:0:0")
```

If post_date is always less than CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), there is no need to include it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 create table wp_posts(
         id int, 
         post_date datetime);

insert into wp_posts(id, post_date)
      values(1, '2023-04-20 08:15:00'),
      (2, '2023-04-21 18:5:00'),
      (3, '2023-04-21 18:1:00'),
      (4, '2023-04-21 18:16:00'),
      (5, '2023-04-21 18:25:00'),
      (6, '2023-04-20 18:30:00');
```

```
select current_timestamp
```

| current_timestamp |
| --- |
| 2023-04-20 18:40:39 |

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE   post_date > now() - interval 1 hour;
```

Output:

| id | post_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-04-21 18:05:00 |
| 3 | 2023-04-21 18:01:00 |
| 4 | 2023-04-21 18:16:00 |
| 5 | 2023-04-21 18:25:00 |
| 6 | 2023-04-20 18:30:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g9ANCTFu)